# `npm create-react-app` command is not working with npm version 6.9.0

Tags: npm, create-react-app

I have successfully used create-react-app before, but now it's not working for some reason. I did the following

```
npm install -g create-react-app
npm create-react-app test
```

But the following shows up instead

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\xxxxx\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.9.0 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

does anyone know what is going on?

EDIT: I was successful with

```
 npx create-react-app test
```

But please help if you know why npm was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npx` comes with **npm 5.2+ and higer** ,use `npx create-react-app test` which is what you used and it worked!!
In the first case and for **npm 5.1 or earlier** you cannot use `npx` and you should be using **create-react-app test** without `npm`

you can use the same command with higher version of `npm` as well and should be fine

This should create the `test` app in the directory you are in.

If you want to use `npm`, you can do `npm init react-app test`

Comment: You can see my answer now, I have edited it using npm. you have to add init after npm